# window.ethereum.isConnected() return false after refresh page

Tags: metamask

According to the documents of MetaMask, `window.ethereum.isConnected()` return `true` if MetaMask is connected to the chain and can send RPC to the chain.

I write a simple web application as follows.
When page load first time, `window.ethereum.isConnected()` return `true` as expected. However, when I refresh page (F5), `window.ethereum.isConnected()` return `false` but MetaMask is connected to the chain.

This seems that the behavior of `window.ethereum.isConnected()` is not as described as in documents of MetaMask.

Any idea?

HTML

```
<body onload="initWallet()">
</body>
```

JavaScript

```
async function initWallet() {
  if(typeof window.ethereum !== 'undefined' && window.ethereum.isMetaMask) {
    console.log('MetaMask is installed.');
    if(window.ethereum.isConnected() {
      console.log('MetaMask is connected.');
    } else {
      console.log('MetaMask is disconnected.');
    }
  }
}
```